# What is causing plasma confinement instability according to Erik Witalis?

Tags: plasma-physics, stability

Erik Witalis mentions problems with traditional plasma confinement like the one in [tokamaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokamak) and particle beams. Instead he mentioned a different technique.

What is the problem with plasma confinement according to Erik Witalis?

What solution does he describe?

[Some of Witalis work](https://scholar.google.se/scholar?hl=sv&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=erik%20witalis&btnG=).

Answer (score 1):

> > The phenomenon of current enhancement (which is also called current multiplication, or current amplification) is potentially unfavorable to beam transport
> >     since a plasma return current above that necessary for current neutralization will
> >     eventually contribute to defocusing of the beam. While several mechanisms
> >     may contribute to this phenomenon, it was found that classical Coulomb collisions alone are insufficient to drive the observed plasma current, but that the
> >     two-stream interaction between beam particles and plasma electrons, which can
> >     produce large-amplitude plasma oscillations, can drive such a plasma current, as
> >     much for ion-beams [81] than for electron-beams [135].

Classical Coulomb collisions are insufficient to drive the observed plasma current.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0409157.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Classical theory considers the movements of particles confined using magnetic fields. At a microscopic area of small enough size, the magnetic field looks like "lines of force" with the electrons and ions rapidly circling them while travelling along them, tracing out helical paths. In this model, particles interact when, say, an ion on one line is at the left-most part of it's orbit around the line while the ion on the next line is at it's right-most part. It's pretty straightforward to predict the rate of collisions based on the particle density *rho*, magnetic field strength *T* and temperature *t*.

Following classical theory, one would expect a random-walk diffusion pattern as the particles collided and were moved to different lines. In this case, the diffusion time varies with T^2, so small increases in magnetic force would increase confinement and it seemed fusion-relevant conditions would be pretty straightforward. However, real-world experiments in the 1940s showed that T^2 didn't hold and it scaled with T. If this Bohm rate was correct, there was no hope of making a fusion machine.

During the early 1950s, they basically ignored the Bohm cased and just hoped it was wrong. No one could see why it would be right, so they basically dreamed up some excuses why it wasn't. And then every single machine they build began leaking plasma at a furious rate, and even Spitzer began to think the Bohm rate was a basic outcome of theory.

Luckily, it wasn't. The missing ingredient was the interactions between the fields caused by the particle motion and the original confining fields. When these were considered, a range of wave-like instabilities and "microinstabilites" appeared. Consider the classic tok layout - as the particles move from the outside edge of the tube to the inside they see an increasing field density which will reflect slower-moving particles like in a magnetic mirror. These produce a current running in the opposite direction, creating a new magnetic field that opposes the original, making the field very bumpy indeed. This sort of interaction tends to appear in all sorts of different fields.

So when you consider things like charge separation and currents that result, the purely classical model simply doesn't work very well for anything beyond a fairly limited set of conditions.